# Trouble-shooting issues with Ubiquiti NS-5ACL NanoStation

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ubiquity

I have two of these configured as a wireless link (one a station the other an access point) i.e. a virtual ethernet cable. Today the access point end reports no connection and I cannot figure out how to diagnose the issue.

I *thought* I should be able to access a web-based control panel (similar to a router) by simply typing each device's IP address into my browser, while my router shows both device's IP addresses both report non-connection when I try. This might *be* the problem or it might be I am entering the wrong URL but I cannot find the documentation to double-check, every guide I can find talks about using their app which is not how I did it before.

Can anyone tell me definitively what the local URL should be?

Comment: When you say "the access point reports no connection" is this based just on the LEDs on the device itself, or did I misunderstand that you're not able to access the AP's web UI?

Comment: @user1686 I mean I can't access either device's web UI, or ping either device, and the devices connected to the AP report no internet. But I'm not certain what the Web UI URL _is_